# Gulp plugin error : Error in plugin 'run-sequence' : An error occured in task 'ngconstant:prod'

Tags: gulp, jhipster

I use jhipster and i have this error in gulp task ?

Error in plugin 'run-sequence'
Message:
    An error occured in task 'ngconstant:prod'.

any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: No details, no help.

Comment: Add your gulpfile + error logs

Answer (score 0):

Try below command :

> npm install --save run-sequence

Hope this will work!!